# tkinter throws TypeError, not sure what it's referencing

Tags: tkinter, typeerror, python-3.7

I'm creating a grid of buttons and then trying to find the location of a button when it is clicked on using tkinter. However, tkinter throws a `TypeError` when the code is ran, and I'm not sure what line it is referencing. I believe the areas in question are shown below, but I can post everything I have written if it is needed.

```
def createbuttongrid(self):
    label = 1
    for row in range(8):
        for column in range(12):

            button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text='Well %s' % label, command=lambda r=row, c=column:self.colorbuttons)
            button.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.colorbuttons)
            self.button_list[button] = (row, column)
            button.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='nsew')
            label += 1

def colorbuttons(self, r, c):
    row = r
    column = c
    print("Row: %s\nColumn: %s" % (row, column))
```

The error I'm getting is below

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[MY_NAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: colorbuttons() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
```

Both of these functions are in a class, including an `__init__` to generate and set up the main window, if it matters.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

I ended up changing some things further downstream, and ended up with the following

```
def createbuttongrid(self):
    label = 1
    for row in range(8):
        for column in range(12):

            button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text='Well %s' % label)
            button.bind("<Button-1>", self.colorbuttons)
            button.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='nsew')
            self.button_list[button] = (row, column)
            label += 1

def colorbuttons(self, event):
    button = event.widget
    print(button, self.button_list[button])
```

Using this, it is possible to obtain the row and column of the buttons in the grid (which is what I was ultimately after, maybe could have specified this earlier). Much thanks to both people that commented here that ultimately pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Please show the actual error. We don't need everything, but we do need just enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: Why are you both using the `command` attriute and also binding to a buttonpress?

Comment: @BryanOakley I updated my post to include the error. As far as using `command` and a bind, I wanted to include a drag-to-select type functionality (like in microsoft excel if you select multiple cells), but was unsure of how to go about doing so. I'm not 100% sure why I have both, but I am unsure of the differences

Comment: When `colorbuttons()` is invoked via the (pointless) ButtonPress-1 binding, it receives a single parameter, the event that caused the invocation.  This would become the `r` parameter (not that it would actually be *usable* as the `r` parameter), but there's nothing to provide the `c` parameter.